# How to get the data from particular range day by day my ranges is different(VBA Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

How to get the data from particular ranges, day by day different ranges is shown in my sheet..i need only available cell data value only required remaining should be blank..

here i pasted my `enter code here`

```
Windows("Daily Operation 14-Oct -13 using vab.XLSM").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range("O3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(TODAY()=RC[-9],""Today EDD"",IF((TODAY()>RC[-9]),""EDD Crossed"",IF((TODAY()+1)=RC[-9],""T+1"",IF(OR((RC[-9]=(TODAY()+2)),(RC[-9]=(TODAY()>=3))),""T+2"",""Future EDD""))))"

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select

ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

ActiveCell.End(xlUp).Select

Selection.End(xlDown).Select

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select

Selection.FillDown
```

Comment: a sample  dummy data and expected result illustration would be helpful. Please provide some. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quite understand what is that you really need. 
But I do have a small code suggestion:
Don't place the file name in `Windows("Daily Operation 14-Oct -13 using vab.XLSM").Activate`.

Store it in a named range on the excel sheet and then use it on the code like this:

```
dim r as range
set r = range("filename")
windows(r.value).activate
```

you could also use something like

```
fname = activewindow.caption`
windows(fname).activate`
```

Placing it like you did could cause you problems because file names and such can often change and on the other hand you want to change code as little as possible.

Cheers,

Udi